# Xampp redirect configured vhost to dashboard

Tags: virtualhost, apache2, xampp

I have XAMPP long time and i am using Apache for PHP websites. I have 5 configured vhosts, projects in same parent directory, with same vhost confing and dns setting. But my last configured vhost, after visit url get redirect to dashborad.

So after give to browser url: xxx.local a get redirect to address: xxx.local/dashboard and i can see some welcome html...

I have no clue what is going on.

Running on Win10, Xampp ver. 7.2.15

C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts:

```
127.0.0.1 first.local
127.0.0.1 second.local
127.0.0.1 xxx.local
```

C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin myEmail@domain.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/Projects/projectName/web/public_html"
    ServerName xxx.local
    ErrorLog "C:/Projects/projectName/logs/error.log"
    CustomLog "C:/Projects/projectName/logs/access.log" combined

    <Directory "C:/Projects/projectName/web">
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Project is in dir 'web' and index.php file is in 'web/public_html'

That same way i have configured more vhost and it works...

Difference is only:

- in dir as projectName is '.'
- all projects has index.php in dir 'public' this project in 'public_html' (configured as document root)

**UPDATE:**

If i delete file 'c:\xampp\htdocs\index.php' after visit url: 'xxx.local' i can see directory ('c:\xampp\htdocs') content. wt?

Comment: The redirect does not come from your Apache, but from the php scripts on that vhost.

Comment: What i am doing wrong? Every other vhost are running correctly...

Comment: Check your php scripts.

Comment: In index.php in path 'C:/Projects/projectName/web/public_html' is only echo and then exit.

Comment: Have you been able to figure this out ? I am having the same problem.